# print result of a node_load()

Tags: nodes

I would like to print the result when calling the `node_load()` function. All I get is an error... How do I get something on my screen?

Here is the code I try:

```
$form = node_load(1473);
print render($form);
```

And the error:

```
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in include() (line 10 of ...
```

How can I display the content of `$form` properly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use the [`node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_view/7) function to prepare the correct output for your required view mode:

```
$view_mode = 'teaser'; // Or 'full' for example

$node = node_load(1473);

$view = node_view($node, $view_mode);

print render($view);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get the array structure of a node you can dot it with the help of below code.

```
<?php echo "<pre>"; print_r(node_load(1473)); echo "</pre>"; ?>
```

Comment: Or dpm(node_load(1473)) if you are using devel.